# magento i need to apply discount 20% for the total if above 50euros but not to the discounted items

Tags: magento, discount

magento i need to apply discount 20% for the total if  above 50euros but not to the discounted items if customers selects some already discounted items that should not include in the total can any one help 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom module or say shopping cart price rule and an event observer to check whether the "special price" is zero or not. If it is "Zero" that means it is not a already discounted product or you can even check the "final price" with the "price" , if the final price is lesser than price it is already discounted.

If these conditions are satisfied get the prices of remaining products prices and discount them then add the already discounted products price to make the total amount.

I hope You understood this concept and write your own module.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a check in view page.
for example

```
$price = $product->getPrice();
$specialprice = $product->getFinalPrice();
if(!empty($specialprice)){

//then your price would be same
}
elseif(empty($specialprice)){

then price would be = $price*20/100;

}
```

hope this would help you and don't forget to like if it was helpful